# How can you count the amount of times one column value appears with another column value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the user_ID that appears most per year in the following table:
     Recipients (msgID, user_ID, time_read)

I can find the distinct year values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_read) as years FROM Recipients
```

And I can find the user_ID that appears the most per year if I hard-code the year:

```
SELECT user_ID u, cnt FROM(SELECT user_ID, COUNT(user_ID) cnt FROM Recipients WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_read) = '2014' GROUP BY user_ID ORDER BY cnt DESC);
```

But I can't figure out how to combine these to get a table that lists the user_ID that appears the most per year.

Thanks

Comment: how is it possible for this question to be both mysql and oracle.  Please pick a platform

Comment: Sorry, must have accidentally clicked mysql

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
   SELECT user_ID, count(user_ID) as cnt, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_read) as year 
   FROM RECIPIENTS
   GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM time_read), user_ID
   ORDER BY year ASC, cnt DESC
```

Comment: I think you need a sub-query if you want to order by those column names.

Comment: Close, it divides the user_ID and counts them per year, but it doesn't only display the max per year.

Comment: @Upgrayded then you actually need a nested select as Hogan mentioned

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier way to do it than this, but I think this would accomplish the end goal:

```
with counts as (
  select
    user_id, extract (year from time_read) as year_id,
    count (*) as cnt
  from
    Recipients
  group by
    user_id, extract (year from time_read)
),
max_values as (
  select
    user_id, year_id, cnt,
    max (cnt) over (partition by year_id) as max_cnt
  from counts
)
select
  user_id, year_id, cnt
from max_values
where cnt = max_cnt
```

There is a possibility you have two or more users tie -- in which case this will list them both.  If you want a tie-breaker, you would have to use `row_number()` instead of `count(1)` in your analytic function.